# jQuery selector gives warning about global scope

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, w3c-validation

I'm trying to tidy up some nested jQuery ajax calls that I have just written. If move some of the code out into another function I get the following warning upon execution.

```
"Element referenced by ID/NAME in the global scope. Use W3C standard document.getElementById() instead."
```

This is one of the calls that is triggering that warning:

```
var access_token = $("input#access_token").val();
```

It's inside a regular javascript out the top level of javascript i.e. Global. How to go about fixing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. Do you receive the same warning if you write `var access_token = $("#access_token").val();` instead?

Comment: which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: What if you do `var access_token = document.getElementById("access_token").value;`?

Comment: That's weird.. right after posting this question the warnings disappeared. I'm almost sure I didn't change anything in my code :-/ Thanks guys.